# Organizing web page code

Tags: php, javascript, dreamweaver, html

Basically I have created web page from scratch and written a lot of code including php and javascript in it.
Now I am wondering is there any tool using Dreamweaver 5 to organize my code?
Tool that automatically arranges, adds spaces, shows errors and and so on...?
Thank you!

Comment: you could have a look at: http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, in Dreamweaver you can try: Commands > Apply Source Formatting.